# Macro that sum different values between worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to the platform and I was wondering if there is a way to write in a "main" sheet the value of total characters for every first column in every sheet in the file

ex: 1st sheet -> count of total characters -> write down into "main sheet" CELL L1 then
2st sheet -> count of total characters -> write down into "main sheet" CELL L2 ...

Here is the code, I've already tried looking for an answer in stack overflow but it doesn't work

Tried this:

```
Dim Sheets As Variant
Dim Sheet As Variant
Sheets = Array("1", "2", "3", "4",..."12")

For Each Sheet In Sheets
   
 For Rowref = 1 To 12
        totalchar = totalchar + Len(Worksheets(Sheet).Range("B2:B100000").Value)
        Worksheets("MAIN").Range ("L" & Rowref)
    Next Rowref
Next Sheet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `For Each` loop in order to run through all the sheets, like in this example:

```
Sub test()
Dim sum As Integer
sum = 0
For Each w In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  sum = sum + w.Range("A1").Value
Next
  MsgBox (sum)
End Sub
```

Have fun :-)

Comment: Thanks! the "for each" loop is running but not the sum of characters lenght... Do you have a suggestion? TY so much!

Comment: In order to calculate the total amount of characters within a column, you can use the formula `=SUM(LEN(A:A))`.

Comment: It works in excel, have you suggestions for VBA?

For Each w In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 Dim totalchar As Long
 Dim index As Long
 totalchar = 0
 For Rowref = 62 To 73
         totalchar = totalchar + WorksheetFunction.sum(Len("A2:A100000"))
      Worksheets("MAIN").Range("L" & Rowref) = totalchar
    Next Rowref
Next w

my aim is to have a column in "main" with calculated cells by the macro with all the sums of total lenghts of the first column for each sheet

Thanks for your time and precious advices

Comment: @Gazometer: concatenating an entire column seems to work better in basic Excel than in VBA. Maybe you can add the formula in your Excel file and retrieve the value in VBA? I believe that would be the easiest.

Comment: I've found a middle solution because I prefer to keep all on the macro, TY for all the support!